# Present UISearchController after button tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am looking for a way how to present a search view with search bar after button is tapped. Am I suppose to create a new UIView with search bar and then after button is tapped segue to that UIView? Or is there a better option?

You can imagine that as searching in Youtube app but you would see search results while typing.

**EDIT:**
So now I managed to present search bar after button is tapped but it is not displaying correctly. Problem is when the search bar is moved lower it is being cut from down:

[image: After button is clicked:]

[image: Typing:]

[image: Clicked on cancel button:]

**My code:**

```
implementation ViewController {
  NSInteger listNo;
  DataClass *dataClass;
  UITableViewController *searchResultsController;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  dataClass = [DataClass getInstance];
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;


  // Prepare Search Controller and Result Controller
  searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
  searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
  searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

  self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
  self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
  self.searchController.delegate = self;
  self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
  self.searchController.searchBar.frame =   CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y + 5,  self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
  [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {
  return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!cell) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:identifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Ahoj";

  return cell;
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
}

- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

}

// Load data to next view
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTable"]) {
    AdditivesTableViewController *atvc = (AdditivesTableViewController    *)segue.destinationViewController;

    switch (listNo) {
        case 0:
            atvc.additivesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray     *)dataClass.nonDangerousAdditives];
            break;
        case 1:
            atvc.additivesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)dataClass.mediumDangerousAdditives];
            break;
        case 2:
            atvc.additivesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)dataClass.dangerousAdditives];
            break;
        case 3:
            atvc.additivesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)dataClass.highDangerousAdditives];
            break;

        default:
            atvc.additivesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)dataClass.allAdditives];
            break;
    }
  }
}



#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)nonDangList:(id)sender {
  listNo = 0;
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTable" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)medDangList:(id)sender {
  listNo = 1;
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTable" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)dangList:(id)sender {
  listNo = 2;
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTable" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)highDangList:(id)sender {
  listNo = 3;
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTable" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)searchAdditive:(id)sender {
  [self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
  [self.searchController setActive:YES];
  [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question. Are you using a UITableView with UISearchDisplayController? Displaying the search bar could just be scrolling the table to display it tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0).

Comment: I am using UIViewController and I have button called "search" in it. As I tap a button I want to present search bar with search result controller. Anyway I guess I have finally managed how to do it.

I am using UISearchController and as soon as button is tapped I do:
`[self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];`
and
`[self.searchController setActive:YES];`

Comment: @Xoroxoxoxoxoso I know this is fairly old, but why don't you put your comment as an answer?